# Mongodb scalable colllection

Tags: mongodb, collections, scalability

What will be the best approach for creating MongDB collection(s) that can be scalable and have best read performance? Following are the assumption

- A user has 100 entries /day. Entries are private to user.
- We may have 200,000 users. So almost  200 * 200,000 = 20M entries a day.
- User likes to view the entries as soon it is inserted.
- User likes to search their own entries even data is 3 months old. In 3 months, 20M* 90
  = 180M entries.
- There are no updates. Only insert and delete.

Option in our mind.

- Sharding based on user name. A .. D in one shard etc. But still it will be very difficult to scale.
- Create one collection for each user. We know it is drastic approach but why not. We are not doing aggregation across user data. Any limitation of number of collection in MongoDB

Any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One collection per user will not work, unfortunately, due to the [limits](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections) on the number of namespaces you can have (24,000).

I think there are a few good directions to go.  You are certainly going to want to use a shard key that distributes uniformly - username would be good.  What are your concerns about its scalability?

You may want to check out [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) (Time to Live) collections, as well as [Read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#read-preference) to let your application read from secondaries.  This can speed up query times by distributing workload.

Answer (score 1):

In the MongoDB world, there is no one best schema design. In MongoDB schema design depends on how the application is going to access the data.

Here are the key questions that you need to have answered in order to design a good schema for MongoDB:

- How much data do you have?
- What are your most common operations?  Will you be mostly inserting new data, updating existing data, or doing queries?
- What are your most common queries?
- What are your most common updates?
- How many I/O operations do you expect per second?

In MongoDB, you have a number of choices: you can embed the data, you can create a linked relationship, you can duplicate and denormalize the data, or you can use a hybrid approach.

@Shelman has already mentioned "Read Preference" and that is something that is worthwhile looking at, in terms of taking advantage of the Secondaries.

Sharding would appear to suit you in terms of scaling out. The [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) on sharding is quite extensive, covers the architecture, fundamentals, deployment, adminstration and the internals (if you're extra keen). I'd highly recommend reading it. However, as @Shelman has said, you will need to wisely pick your shard key. This topic is widely covered on StackOverflow and on the [MongoDB Google User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mongodb-user).

One of the reasons to avoid a sequential shard key is that it will create hotspots on inserts: at any given time a single shard will be taking all the insert load. You may want to choose a compound shard key. There are some good discussions on the Google Group on this:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/yolfc6B3JL8

If you choose something like  { username : 1 , timestamp : 1 } then a user's data will be broken into many chunks if needed and spread across servers.

This is the [exact link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-internals/#sharding-internals-shard-keys) to the docs on choosing a shard key.

=============================

Here are some good general references on MongoDB schema design.

MongoDB presentations:

- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf2011/schemabasics
- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/schema-design-by-example
- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf2011/schemascale
- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/Building-a-MongoDB-Power-Chat-Server

Here is a book about MongoDB schema design that I think you would find useful:

- http://www.manning.com/banker/ (MongoDB in Action)

Here are some sample schema designs:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/
- https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/designing-mongodb-schemas-with-embedded-non-embedded-and-bucket-structures

=============================

Here are some examples of using the 'bucketed' approach in a MongoDB schema design:

- https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/designing-mongodb-schemas-with-embedded-non-embedded-and-bucket-structures
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/#hybrid-schema-design
- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/Building-a-MongoDB-Power-Chat-Server
  (Video 3)

=============================

Finally some recent sharding presentations from MongoNYC:

- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/sharding-overview
- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/Sharding-Best-Practices-Advanced

Comment: Thanks for the detail reply. I will go through with the attcahed links. Thanks again.